# SNMPV2C agent accepts the SNMPV1 requests

Tags: snmp

Is SnmpV2C Agent replies the SNMPV1 request? any backward compatibility for accepting v1 request in v2cAgent?

Answer (score 1):

If the agent supports RFC 1908, then it should support both v1 and v2c.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1908

But I think the v2c can also refuse to serve v1 requests, as RFC 1908 is not a "must".

Comment: Hi Lex, rfc 1908 is not implemented in agent side . But any backward compatibility to process snmpv1Requests in snmpv2c agent . Because both packets are same structure(except getbulk &trap). some of the v2c agents are accepts lower version(v1) of requests , not higher level.

Comment: Your "because" won't be able to change the agent developers' mind.